# Share function doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, share

I wrote this code for a share action.

I want it to share text+bitmap.

It doesn't give me an error - it just doesn't do anything.

```
case R.id.share:
            int  myinfoPos = info.position;
            Movie myMovie= myMovies.get(myinfoPos);
            int myMovieID=myMovie.id;
            DBCommands db = new DBCommands(con);
            Cursor c = db.getmovieById(myMovieID);
            String text = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBConstants.SUBJECT));
            String getBit = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBConstants.PHOTOENCODE));
            Bitmap myBitmapAgain = db.decodeBase64(getBit);
            //Uri pictureUri = db.decodeBase64(myBitmapAgain);
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myBitmapAgain);
            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            con.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share images..."));
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no requirement for an `ACTION_SEND` `Activity` to support both `EXTRA_TEXT` and `EXTRA_STREAM`. [The docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) indicate that you can include one of those two extras (" get*Extra can have either a EXTRA_TEXT or EXTRA_STREAM field, containing the data to be sent").

Second, [`EXTRA_STREAM` is documented as](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM):

> A content: URI holding a stream of data associated with the Intent, used with ACTION_SEND to supply the data being sent.

You are not providing a `Uri`. You are providing a `Bitmap`. You need to create a `ContentProvider` to serve this `Bitmap`, or write it to a file and use `FileProvider`.